# Intersection between two HashSets in Java 8

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream, hashset

I have an object as following :

```
public Class MyObjDTO {
    private Long id;
    private Boolean checked;

    //getter and setters

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        Long id = getId();
        return (id == null ? super.hashCode() : id.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof MyObjDTO))
            return false;
        Long id = getId();
        Long objId = ((MyObjDTO) obj).getId();
        if (id.equals(objId)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have two hash sets containing some instances from this object :

```
HashSet oldSet = new HashSet();
oldSet.add(new MyObjDTO(1,true));
oldSet.add(new MyObjDTO(2,true));
oldSet.add(new MyObjDTO(3,false));

HashSet newSet = new HashSet();
newSet.add(new MyObjDTO(1,false));
newSet.add(new MyObjDTO(2,true));
newSet.add(new MyObjDTO(4,true));
```

So what I want to do here is to select objects that are in the `newSet` and not in the `oldSet`, in this case its : `new MyObjDTO(4,true)` which I did using this :

```
Stream<MyObjDTO> toInsert = newSet.stream().filter(e -> !oldSet.contains(e));
```

Then I want to select objects that are in the `oldSet` and not in the `newSet`, in this case its :`new MyObjDTO(3,false)` which I did using this :

```
Stream<MyObjDTO> toRemove = oldSet.stream().filter(e -> !newSet.contains(e));
```

The last step is that I want to select the objects that are in both newSet and oldSet but they have a different value for the attribute `checked` , in this case it's : `new MyObjDTO(1,false)`.
What I tried is this :

```
Stream<MyObjDTO> toUpdate = oldSet.stream().filter(newSet::contains);
```

But this one will return both `new MyObjDTO(1,false)` and `new MyObjDTO(2,true)`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: What are you gonna do with these streams?

Comment: @Holger Insert, Remove or Update my objects in the database.

Comment: Do you need the intersection between two `Set`s? Why not using the old and reliable `retainAll` method? According to `Set` javadoc if the argument passing to the `retainAll` method is also a set the result is the intersection of them.

Comment: @STaefi because I want to filter objects that have same id and different checked value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods violate their basic contract. As per the [javadoc of `hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Your implementation of `hashCode()` does not follow this contract. Your first step should be to fix that.

Secondly, since Java 1.2 (nearly 20 years ago), java has provided the method [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) that does exactly what you want to do for the first part:

```
// Given these 2 sets:
HashSet<MyObjDTO> oldSet = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<MyObjDTO> newSet = new HashSet<>();

HashSet<MyObjDTO> onlyInNew = new HashSet<>(newSet);
onlyInNew.removeAll(oldSet);
// similar for onlyInOld
```

For the second part, you'll need to create a `Map` to find and get the object out:

```
Map<MyObjDTO, MyObjDTO> map = new HashMap<>O;
oldSet.forEach(o -> map.put(o, o);

HashSet<MyObjDTO> updated = new HashSet<>(newSet);
updated.removeIf(o -> oldSet.contains(o) && o.getChecked()() != map.get(o).getChecked());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't figure out how my implementation of `hashCode()` is not following the `hashCode()` constraint.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki you have edited your question since I saw it and changed the implementation; it was just `return super.hashCode();`. It's fine now

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

One way is to first use a map and then adjust your filter condition:

```
Map<MyObjDTO, Boolean> map = newSet.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), MyObjDTO::getChecked));

Stream<MyObjDTO> toUpdate = oldSet.stream()
    .filter(old -> newSet.contains(old) && old.getChecked() != map.get(old));
```

Comment: what is `Function` ?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki `Function` is `java.util.function.Function` interface. You can replace `Function.identity()` with `a -> a`. It means to leave the same object as the key of the map

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I think that guava had somethig like this via `Sets#intersections`..

Comment: This will return objects where I have both the same id and checked value, where I want objects that have the same id but a different checked value.

Answer (score 1):

In the last step, you rely on the `equals()` method of the DTO :

```
Stream<FonctionnaliteDTO> toUpdate = oldSet.stream().filter(newSet::contains);
```

The method uses only the id `field` to determinate object equality.
You don't want to do that.
You want to filter on a specific field : `checked`.

Besides, you should perform the operation on the result of the intersection of the two Sets.

Note that you should use simply `Collection.retainAll()` to compute the intersection between two collections:

```
Set<MyObjDTO> set = ...
Set<MyObjDTO> setTwo = ...

set.retainAll(setTwo);
```

Then you can filter objects that have both same `id` and `checked` value by using a double loop : for + iterator.

```
for (MyObjDTO dto : set){
   for (Iterator<MyObjDTO> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();){

      MyObjDTO otherDto = it.next();
      if (otherDto.getId().equals(dto.getId()) && 
           otherDto.getChecked() == dto.getChecked()){
         it.remove();
      }
   }
}
```

You could do that with Stream but IHMO it could be less readable.

Comment: I would prefer doing that using Stream.